# Encoding issue: Decoding Monster Characters / mojibake strings

Tags: character-encoding

I have a piece of "monster character" sentence (someone sent it to me).

> æ��è©²å��è¬�: å�¨å®¶è£¡æ�¯ä¸�å�¯ä»¥è¬�æ°�ä¸»ç��ã��æ��ä»¥,
>   æ��æ��ç�¶å�ºç�¾ç³¾ç´�, ä¸�ä½�ä¸�å�¯ä»¥ç��é �,
>   é��å�¯è�½æ��ç¯�å¤�ç��æ��... ä½�å¤§ç��, å�¯æ��è®�ä¸�è®�...

Is there any way to decode it back to normal character?

Comment: Not without knowing the encodings originally involved.

Comment: What is it supposed to be? doesn't look like unicode mangled into (say) iso-8859.

Comment: Without information about what the actual byte values are, this is going to be pure guesswork.  Could you add a hex dump please?

Comment: I guess it is either BIG5 / GB-2312

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "monster character" might mean?

Comment: "monster character" in design industry means contents with incorrect encoding.

Comment: `mojibake` is the usual term in English, I think. (Or luanma, if you are Chinese).

Comment: Does your 'original' text have the Unicode replacement characters (�)? If so, you won't be able to convert since the text is already lost.

Comment: @nneonneo agreed with you. the contents may already be lost in translation.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is not really a solution, but there are some software in the Internet provides encoding fixing functions that can do the job.

One of them is a Chinese software ( http://www.cpatch.org/thread-12818-1-1.html ). I put the link here, in case someone is looking for it.

I tried to use PHP function `mb_detect_encoding` and `iconv`, but none of them can convert the string successfully. The data may be permanently lost, due to incomplete copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

It is, theoretically, possible.

You can reverse various encodings. There's a tool for doing this with Russian [here](http://2cyr.com/decode/), for instance.

Of course it would be much better to do this automatically; this can be done because something similar is done by programs like Microsoft Word when it opens a file. If you try to open binary files with Word, you'll see that it sometimes prompts you to choose an encoding, because it couldn't find one, and shows a list of the most likely ones.

I presume the way this is done is checking statistics about character occurrances. For example, in English "e" and "t" happen much more often than "q" and "j". This is long known; Morse code uses only one dot and one dash for "e" and "t" and four dots and dashes for "q" and "j" for this reason.

So an hypotetical tool that does this would probably try a lot of encoding combinations (a lot!) and check which one looks most like a real language.

Other heuristics could be a dictionary for each language, but this starts to become a very intensive process.